# Select cells on a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, timetable

I want to select cells in a time table by clicking and dragging, while limiting the selection only happens on the row (say row A) where the selection starts - do nothing if the cursor moves out of row A, and once it's back to row A, select the cells between the first cell and current cell (inclusive).

Currently the general selection works (I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/frank2048/ocu36uwk/5/)), but I cannot limit the selection on the row where the selection starts, I realized the reason is I cannot get the row and column index in the event handlers, but cannot figure out why:

```
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var row = -1;    // row to start a selection

    $("#our_table td")
        .mousedown(function () {
        isMouseDown = true;

        row = $(this).parent().index();    // doesn't work!!!

        return false; // prevent text selection
    })
```

I found an example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/rxT5z/10/) where the row/col index can be retrieved in hover event, but when I put the script into mine, even the selection doesn't work :(

I'm new to this JavaScript stuff, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ocu36uwk/10/

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using jQuery 1.3.2? It's quite an old version of jQuery.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, your fiddle is exactly the same as mine. Did you forget to click "Update" to save it? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @dreyescat, I'd say I had no idea how old is with jQuery 1.3.2 when I fork the code from another fiddle. Thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question:

http://jsfiddle.net/ocu36uwk/11/

use `var $tr;` to store current row

in `.mousedown` function set current row `$tr = $(this).parent();`

in `.mouseove` function check does the rows are equal:

```
if (isMouseDown && ($tr[0] === $(this).parent()[0]))
```

Comment: dm4web and Jerodev, many thanks to your guys, I finally made it based on your replies: http://jsfiddle.net/frank2048/ocu36uwk/13/

Comment: Currently I use `$tr[0].cells[i].className = "highlighted";` to select multiple cells in a loop, probably this is not a good implementation. Any better way to use addClass() to do this?

Comment: $($tr[0].cells[i]).addClass("highlighted");

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the element you want the index from.

These functions should return the index of the row and column of the selected element. You first find a collection of elements, and in the index function you specify the element from the collection you want the index from.

```
var col = $(this).parent().find("td").index($(this));
var row = $(this).parent().parent().find("tr").index($(this).parent());
```